# Why can I use a PDF when computing bayes rule?

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-function

My understanding is that PDFs are 0-valued at all individual points, and only when we integrate over a specific region do we get a non-zero value. However, my professor keeps using PDFs when evaluating Bayes rule, including evaluating them at single points.

I also (I thought) understand the difference between a PDF and the actual probability of an event, so I'm also confused why we can use the PDF at all in Bayes rule, since it is the derivative of the CDF / doesn't actually represent probability at a single point, regardless of whether its mechanically possible to evaluate it at a single point.

Below is an illustrative example from the class

> Your daily commute is distributed normally with mean 10 minutes and
>   standard deviation 2 minutes if there no convention downtown.
>
> However, conventions are scheduled for roughly 1 in 5 days, and your
>   commute time is distributed normally with mean 15 minutes and standard
>   deviation 3 minutes if there is a convention. Let Y be your commute
>   time and θ = 1 indicate there is a convention and θ = 0 if there is no
>   convention.
>
> Y | θ = 0 ~ Normal(10, 4).
>
> Give an expression for the probability there was a convention downtown given that your commute time was Y = 16 minutes.
>
> $p(θ = 1|Y = 16) = \frac{\displaystyle f(16|1)π(1)}{\displaystyle f(16|0)π(0) + f(16|1)π(1)}
> = \frac{\displaystyle \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2 \pi}}exp\big\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{y - 15}{3} \right)^2\big\} 0.2}{\displaystyle f(16|0)π(0) + f(16|1)π(1)} ...$

Why can the PDF be used like this, and why are we allowed to evaluate it at a single point?

Answer (score 4):

The professor is not using a pdf, the professor is using a likelihood.

Consider the following pdf: $$f(x_i|\mu)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x_i-\mu)^2},\forall{x_i}\in\Re.$$  You are correct that $\Pr(x_1=5)=0$ as there is no area.

However, the professor is not using a density, the professor is using a likelihood.  Consider the following likelihood for the same problem:$$g(x_i|\mu)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x_i-\mu)^2},\forall\mu\in\Re.$$

Please note the subtle difference.  In the pdf, the data is random and the parameter is fixed.  Now the data is fixed, but the parameter is random.  Randomness, in this case, is understood as uncertainty rather than just chance.

It is still true that $\Pr(\mu=k|x_1=5)=0$, but a likelihood is not a probability.  It does not need to sum to unity.  So what you are getting is a pdf about $\mu$ when you calculate the posterior.  If $\Pr(\mu=k)\propto{1}$, noting that this is an improper prior and can often result in an answer that does not sum to one but does in this case, you end up with the following density.  $$h(\mu|x_1=5)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(5-\mu)^2}.$$

Of course, this simplification collapses on the second observation.  This particular choice of distributions is rather unfortunate because it does not combine well in any circumstance.  It has no conjugate prior and it is ill-behaved in many aspects.  It is just easy to type.

Note that if $x_2=7$ and the observations are independent, then you end up with $$h(\mu|x_1=5;x_2=7)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{1+(5-\mu)^2}\frac{1}{1+(7-\mu)^2}/\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{1+(5-\mu)^2}\frac{1}{1+(7-\mu)^2}\mathrm{d}\mu\right].$$

Fortunately, and because of magic handwaving from choosing convenient samples, this simplifies to $$h(\mu|x_1=5;x_2=7)=\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^4-24x^3+216x^2-864x+1300},\forall\mu\in\Re.$$

In this process, $h$ is a density function.  It is still only a probability when there is an interval.

Visually, you can see it below noting that the posterior density cannot possibly be the density that nature uses.
[image: posterior]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are confused between the terms: pdf, pmf, probability

Your understanding that, quote: "that PDFs are 0-valued at all individual points" is wrong. For a continuous random variable, probability it takes a certain value is `0`, but pdf is not `0`.

The other minor thing: $p(\theta = 1 | Y = 16)$ is not a pdf, it is a pmf (conditional), because $\theta$ is a discrete random variable, not continuous.

Lastly, Bayes rule in the most basic form defined for the discrete random variables $\theta$, $Y$, however it can be extended to all the other variants: 1. $\theta$ - continuous, $Y$ - discrete 2. $\theta$ - discrete, and $Y$ - continuous. and finally, 3. both $\theta$, $Y$ - continuous.

As you pointed out, probability $P(X = x) = 0$ for the continuous random variables, in that case Bayes rule operates with density functions, instead of probabilities $P$

The example you posted is correct form of Bayes rule for $\theta$ - discrete and $Y$ - continuous (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Random_variables)